# Can't access column in LINQ resultset

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, datatable

I'm accessing a small Access database and put some of the tables inside a dataset. Then, I need to query those tables with LINQ. I'm pretty new with LINQ and I don't understand what is wrong with the following code :

```
DataTable cours = autOuvrDS.Tables["cours"];
DataTable etudiants = autOuvrDS.Tables["etudiants"];
DataTable resultats = autOuvrDS.Tables["resultats"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from etudiant in etudiants.AsEnumerable()
                             join resultat in resultats.AsEnumerable()
                             on etudiant.Field<string>("matricule") equals resultat.Field<string>("matricule")
                             join cour in cours.AsEnumerable()
                             on resultat.Field<string>("sigle") equals cour.Field<string>("sigle")
                             select etudiant;

DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Then I loop trough each row to print the data :

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                row.Field<string>("Prenom") + "\t\t" +
                row.Field<string>("Nom") + "\t\t" +
                row.Field<string>("Sigle") + "\t\t" +   /// PROGRAM CRASH HERE
                row.Field<string>("Cours") + "\t\t"
                );
        }
```

And get the following error when I execute the program : "Additional information: Column 'Sigle' does not belong to table ."

The column "Sigle" is part of the "cours" table, which I've joined with the query, so I would have tought the query would select the columns from the joined tables, but it seems it's not the case.. So how can I select columns from other tables??

Comment: just put the berakpoint at PROGRAM CRASH HERE and check either you are accessing with wrong column name or may be casting to wrong data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is joining three sets of `DataRow` objects, then selecting one of those `DataRow` objects as the output.  The resultant `table` object contains rows that originate in the `etudiants` source table only.

If you want only the fields you listed, you could declare a structure to hold the results similar to this:

```
public struct QueryResult
{
    public string Prenom;
    public string Nom;
    public string Sigle;
    public string Cours;
}
```

Then when you want to run the query:

```
var query = 
    from etudiant in etudiants.AsEnumerable()
    join resultat in resultats.AsEnumerable()
    on etudiant.Field<string>("matricule") equals resultat.Field<string>("matricule")
    join cour in cours.AsEnumerable()
    on resultat.Field<string>("sigle") equals cour.Field<string>("sigle")
    select new QueryResult
    {
        Prenom = etudiant.Field<string>("Prenom"),
        Nom = etudiant.Field<string>("Nom"),
        Sigle = resultat.Field<string>("Sigle"),
        Cours = resultat.Field<string>("Cours")
    };

List<QueryResult> results = query.ToList();

foreach (QueryResult row in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\t",
        row.Prenom, row.Nom, row.Sigle, row.Cours
    );
}
```

You could use an anonymous type, but only if the results are not being used anywhere outside the method that creates the instance.  Trust me on this, it's simpler to declare structures unless the results are completely internal to a single method.

---

*Update with `DataTable` implementation:*

This will do the same query and produce a `DataTable` filled with a selection of field values from the results:

```
var query = 
    from etudiant in etudiants.AsEnumerable()
    join resultat in resultats.AsEnumerable()
    on etudiant.Field<string>("matricule") equals resultat.Field<string>("matricule")
    join cour in cours.AsEnumerable()
    on resultat.Field<string>("sigle") equals cour.Field<string>("sigle")
    select new { etudiant, cour };


// Définir la structure de la table de sortie
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Prenom", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Nom", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Sigle", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Cours", typeof(string));

// Remplir la table de sortie à partir la requête
foreach (var row in query)
{
    DataRow newrow = table.NewRow();
    newrow["Prenom"] = row.etudiant.Field<string>("Prenom");
    newrow["Nom"] = row.etudiant.Field<string>("Nom");
    newrow["Sigle"] = row.cour.Field<string>("Sigle");
    newrow["Cours"] = row.cour.Field<string>("Cours");
    table.Rows.Add(newrow);
}
```

While there's probably a more efficient way to achieve this, both in code and actual run time, the fact that you're constrained to using a `DataTable` instead of a more .NET-centric format is something that I wouldn't normally face.

Comment: This is working, but I need to put the resultset inside a DataTable. I tried switching back the query to a "IEnumerable<DataRow>" instead of "var", but then I get an error on the second join : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Why must you have a `DataTable`?  What format should this `DataTable` have?

Comment: Actually this is part of a homework problem which ask to put the resulset inside a DataTable, so there's no real significant reason other than this to put it inside a table.. I'm not too sure, what're you meaning about the format of the table?

Comment: By *format* I mean what columns should it have, of what types, etc.  A `DataTable` without a format is basically useless.  I've updated my answer with code that produces a `DataTable`, but I would never suggest this sort of code in production.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry for not specifying the format sooner, but the columns are indeed all of string type. It's ok if it's not production code since it's only for learning purpose.. Tough now I'm wondering why they're asking us to put the result inside a DataTable if it's such a hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that Sigle belongs to `cours` table, but in your LINQ query you select data only from `etudiants` table: `select etudiant`. So that column can't be in your output. Take a look more carefully at your code.